# Correct data types for loaded Pascal dll in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, pascal

I´m loading a Pascal dll in Python and want to execute the function loadIRB, whose input and output parameters are defined as follows:

loadIRB

```
function loadIRB(const fn: PAnsiChar ) : PtrUInt;
```

- Parameter: fn(PAnsiChar): Pathname
- Return: PtrUInt: 0 - failure
      else: reference to file handle

I tried the following code and some modifications, but I absolutely don´t know, what I´m doing wrong, since the function is always returning a NULL pointer. The loading of the dll is working and AA00.irb is the file I want to open. Can somebody help me with this?

```
class RETURN(Structure):
_fields_ = [
            ("return_pt", c_uint),
           ]

dll = windll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
string1 = "AA00.irb"
b_string1 = string1.encode('ansi')
func = dll.loadIRB
func.argtypes = [c_char_p]
func.restype = POINTER(RETURN)
ret = func(b_string1)
```

Comment: May be problem in a calling conventions, see: http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/c261c/ASM/Procedures/P77_0070_pascal_stdcall.htm and https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu71.html

Comment: How is *PtrUInt* defined (in *Delphi*)? Also, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: The "ansi" in pascal PAnsiChar does not mean "ansi encoding", it refers to the way the string is stored in memory. A pascal AnsiChar is a null-terminated string, but also contains a length and a reference count. I believe Python can not cope with it natively.